# Issue with querying the database after a table is deleted

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I had a table `table_one` and another table `table_two`.

I had designed `table_two` somewhat like this:

```
class TableTwo(models.Model):
     sample_content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, blank=True, null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    sample_content_type_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=True, null=True
    )
    sample_object = GenericForeignKey(
        'sample_content_type',
        'sample_content_type_id'
    )
```

I had rows in `table_two` which had `GenericForeignKey` relation with `table_two` content types. Later I had to delete `table_one`.

Now whenever I tried to query `table_two` I was facing errors and fixed that by deleting all the rows which had relation with `table_one`. I was expecting once the table is deleted all the data related with that table in `table_two` would also be deleted. I want to know how django handles such situations.

FYI: This is the error I got

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '_base_manager'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.